# select datas between ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Into an Oracle DB i have two tables, TABLE A and TABLE B,

TABLE B have a range of dates and i have to find if a YEAR in table A is before the start date, after the finish date or if is not in the range

```
TABLE A
+-----+-----+
|NAME |YEAR |
+-----+------
|R1   |2016 |
|R1   |2015 |
|R1   |2014 |
|R1   |2013 |
|R2   |2016 |
|R2   |2015 |
|R2   |2014 |
|R2   |2013 |
+-----+-----+

TABLE B
+----+---------+----------+
|NAME|YEARSTART|YEARFINISH|
+----+---------+----------+
|R1  |2015     |2016      |
|R1  |2013     |2013      |
|R2  |2016     |2016      |
|R2  |2013     |2014      |
+----+---------+----------+


RESULT
+----+----+
|NAME|YEAR|
+----+----+
|R1  |2014|
|R2  |2015|
+----+----+
```

i found when a record is before the lower start date and after the higthest finish date

but how to find if a year is not in a range?

in my example i got R1 2014 and R2 2015 which are not in the range, how to identify them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row from table A if same name doesn't exist in table b with overlapping years:

```
select ta.name, ta.year
from tablea ta
where not exists (select 1 from tableb tb
                  where ta.name = tb.name
                    and ta.year between tb.yearstart and tb.yearend)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a left join:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.NAME = b.NAME 
                  AND a.YEAR >= b.YEARSTART 
                  AND a.YEAR <= b.YEARFINISH
WHERE b.NAME IS NULL
```